# How to set 00:00:00 using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to get current date but time should be `00:00:00.000`

I've try this:

```
var m = moment();
m.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0});
console.log(m.toISOString());
```

but I've got: `2016-01-12T23:00:00.000Z` why 23 and not 00?

Comment: you can exclude, if you don't want time. what is real intention to keep 00:00:00

Comment: @Venkatraman I need milliseconds for current day.

Comment: You could just use `moment().startOf("day");` (with an optional `.utc()` in between if that's what you need).

Comment: startDate.utcOffset(0);
      startDate.set({
        hour: 0,
        minute: 0,
        second: 0,
        millisecond: 0,
      });

Comment: @nawazanjum this is exactly as accepted answer.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

Moment.js stores dates it utc and can apply different timezones to it. By default it applies your local timezone. 
If you want to set time on utc date time you need to specify utc timezone.

Try the following code:

```
var m = moment().utcOffset(0);
m.set({hour:0,minute:0,second:0,millisecond:0})
m.toISOString()
m.format()
```

Answer (score 13):

```js
var time = moment().toDate();  // This will return a copy of the Date that the moment uses

time.setHours(0);
time.setMinutes(0);
time.setSeconds(0);
time.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Comment: I want current date, but time should be 00:00:00

Comment: How about just moment().startOf('day') ? It would set the time to the start of the current day.

Answer (score 0):

You've not shown how you're creating the string `2016-01-12T23:00:00.000Z`, but I assume via `.format()`.

Anyway, `.set()` is using your local time zone, but the `Z` in the time string indicates [zero time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC), otherwise known as UTC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators

So I assume your local timezone is 23 hours from UTC?

[saikumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762470/366529) showed how to load the time in as UTC, but the other option is to use a `.format()` call that outputs using your local timezone, rather than UTC.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: I've used `toISOString()` method.

Comment: toISOString() returns the date in UTC, rather than your local timezone. http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/

Comment: The "Z" is Zero UTC offset: "The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z"." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString

Comment: @Mawaheb Ah, so it is, thanks for the correction. I got slightly confused as Zulu time is also the Zero timezone AKA UTC AKA GMT https://greenwichmeantime.com/info/zulu/