# Javascript UTC Date different values

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have a date  in the format dd.mm.yyyy

I use a function to convert this date to MM-DD-YYYY

```
stringToStringDateFormat(objectData: any): string {
    return moment(objectData, 'DD.MM.YYYY').format('MM-DD-YYYY');
}
```

I want to set hours minutes and seconds to 0
ad send the date in ISO format so i used the following code :

```
new Date(new Date(this.stringToStringDateFormat("19.07.2021")).setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)).toISOString();
```

yet the issue I have is I get a different day
for example in this case I get 2021-07-**18**T00:00:00.000Z
while in reality, it should be 2021-07-**19**T00:00:00.000Z

how can I get my code to get me the same date I provided and not the date -1 ?

Comment: What date does `this.stringToStringDateFormat("19.07.2021")` return. Might be an issue where it's accounting for your local time zone and returning e.g. `2021-07-18 T23:00:00Z` or `2021-07-19 0:00:00 UTC-1`.

Comment: no that function only changes the format and returns "07-19-2021"

Comment: Why are you using moment for such a simple string manipulation? Just split it and create a UTC date directly.

Comment: @R0b0t0 Then how does your code even work? That means you're calling `.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)` on a string which should error. Also seems like the brackets are mismatched in general, and for some reason you're using the Date constructor twice?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs  I have added the missing bracked

Comment: @R0b0t0 then we're back to what I mentioned: Your `new Date('07-19-2021')` is probably returning something like `2021-07-18 00:00:00 UTC-1` which is actually `23:00` of the previous day in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here using [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) and adjusting the month to account for zero index.

```js
const [d, m, y] = `19.07.2021`.split('.').map(Number);

console.log(new Date(Date.UTC(y, (m - 1), d)).toISOString()); // months are 0 indexed
```

Comment: The use of `.map(Number)` is redundant, leaving *d*, *m* and *y* as strings is fine. :-)

Comment: True! but I thought I'd be explicit. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Created a new function that sets the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0 and returns the date string in the correct format. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34762651/10213537) answer for a more detailed look on the methods I used.

```js
function stringToStringDateFormatStartDay(objectData) {
  const newD = moment(objectData, "DD.MM.YYYY").utcOffset(0).set({
    hour: 0,
    minute: 0,
    second: 0,
    millisecond: 0
  });
  newD.toISOString();
  newD.format("MM-DD-YYYY");
  return newD;
}

const d = stringToStringDateFormatStartDay("19.07.2021");
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing with a library to create an interim unsupported format then parsing with the built–in parser is not a good idea.

If you just want to reformat dd.mm.yyyy as yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:00Z then just reformat the string, there is no need to convert to Date object or use a library:

```js
function reformatTimestamp(s) {
  return `${s.split(/\D/).reverse().join('-')}T00:00:00Z`;
}

console.log(reformatTimestamp('19.07.2021'));
```